# Getting Rid of Table Borders in HTML Emails

Tags: html, html-table, border, html-email

I'm working on an HTML email campaign (no CSS allowed) so I'm forced to use tables, something I'm not super familiar with. I've got everything looking right EXCEPT the table borders. Whenever I create a new `<tr>` I cannot for the life of me get rid of the inner border around the content. I have tried a few tricks (`border="0px"`, `bordercolor="white"`, `bordercolor="#ffffff"`, etc), but whenever I send a test message, the borders still show up black around my text and images.

This is really messing with my design flow.
Is there any trick I don't know to getting rid of HTML table borders? Help!

Comment: that should read" whenever I create a new <tr>

Comment: You can still use CSS inline with HTML, so is CSS still out?

Comment: what email client? Can you trace where the border is coming from at all? is it a web based client?

Comment: the border shows up in google business apps email, yahoo and aol. i'm using an online program called lyris to build the email but am coding the whole thing, not using the wysiwyg editor.

Comment: fixed it! frame= and rules= !

Answer (score 9):

```
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style = "border-collapse: collapse;">
```

Answer (score 7):

Apply this:

```
style = "border-collapse: collapse;"
```

To every table cell, the border should not be visible anymore.

Answer (score 3):

If the content is an image, try `<td valign="top">` for all `<td>` with images inside.
Besides that, the table tag should be `<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" ...>`. One more tip, use inline style for the borders that you want.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

In head:

```
  <style type="text/css">
    table td {border-collapse: collapse;}
  </style>
```

Table:

```
<table width="300" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="border:2px solid #000000;">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%" bgcolor="#999999" style="padding:20px;">
    ...
    </td>
    <td width="50%" bgcolor="#888888" style="padding:20px;">
    ...
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="50%" bgcolor="#777777" style="padding:20px;">
    ...
    </td>
    <td width="50%" bgcolor="#666666" style="padding:20px;">
    ...
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also, always keep cellpadding and cellspacing at zero. Use padding in your cells if you want spacing.

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of the table borders, use `<table border="0">`.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
  <!-- ... -->
</table>
```

? Such inline CSS should work fine even in HTML email.

Comment: I tried the border-collapse and it worked on removing the entire table border, but not the individual table row border. This is what I have so far:  <table cellpadding="20px" bgcolor="ffffff" width="900px" border="1px" bordercolor="cfb0aa">
      <tbody>
        <tr bordercolor="white"> <td><!--------> </td> </tr></tbody> </table>                                                                        I want to get rid of the border around the <tr>...</tr>, but nothing I've tried will remove it in the actual email.

Comment: I should add that when I preview the email it looks fine, but when it is actually delivered the inner <tr> border still remains.

Comment: @Ben, that's strange. Does it happen in all email programs/providers? Either way, you shouldn't use `px` in html attributes - http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/dtd.html#Length

Answer (score 1):

Use `<table border="0">` without px?

Comment: This is just a repeat of [this existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7363705).

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this tip that actually works (at least for iOS):

> To prevent [hairline borders] from happening nest the problematic
>   table into a new table with a background color that matches that of
>   the inner table.

*Source*: http://www.informz.com/blog/template-design/quick-tip-removing-hairline-borders-in-html-emails-on-iphone-ipad/ (includes photos of source code)

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me:

```html
border: 0px solid white;
border-collapse: collapse;
```