# How to get rid of html table border in email template

Tags: html, html-table, outlook

I created email template in HTML, but it is not working as expected. To be precise then html table border part is not working in outlook. I have set border 0, but it is still appear in outlook email. If I run html in whatever editor then borders are not displayed.

I have googeled a lot and have tried different approaches, what I found, but non of those were helpful (different styles, border-collapse, set borders 0 on td and tr level etc).

Plain html look like this:

```html
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" 
align="center" bgcolor="#fff">
<tbody>
<tr bgcolor="#fff">
<td>Test</td>
<td>Test</td>
<td>Test</td>
<td>Test</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Hopefully someone have faced similar problem and knows how to fix this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Rid of Table Borders in HTML Emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303254/getting-rid-of-table-borders-in-html-emails)

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to add comments there. But went through this topic as well previously, but non of the answers there were helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use style="border: none"

```html
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" 
align="center" bgcolor="#fff" style="border: none">
<tbody>
<tr bgcolor="#fff">
<td>Test</td>
<td>Test</td>
<td>Test</td>
<td>Test</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

or using style = "border-collapse: collapse;"

```html
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" 
align="center" bgcolor="#fff" style = "border-collapse: collapse;">
<tbody>
<tr bgcolor="#fff">
<td>Test</td>
<td>Test</td>
<td>Test</td>
<td>Test</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Tried both options already before, but no luck. In html editor it looks ok, but not in outlook.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone reading this in December 2021 and onwards: refrain from using `border-collapse: collapse` with `padding`. Since a recent Office 365 update, `border-collapse: collapse` causes emails to show gaps with the size of the stated padding as if they were margins. `border="0"` or `border:0;` is sufficient in most of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `table { border-collapse:collapse !important; }` in the head of your email.

There isn't any need to declare this on every single table.

Comment: Unfortunately it wont help.

Comment: Are you in a position to post all of your code, even if placeholders are included. There may be something else at play.